# Responsive Email - Media Queried Images Won't Load

Tags: email, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive email design where several images switch out for the smaller screens. I've reformatted tables and tds several times and the smaller images don't show. The images are live online. Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Happy St. Patrick's Day</title>
<style type="text/css">

            body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
                table.one { width: 480px !important; }
                table.two { width: 480px !important; }
                table.three { width: 480px !important; }
                table.four { width: 480px !important; }
                table.five { width: 480px !important; }
                td.shamtop img { display: none; }
                td.shamtop { background: #00A160 url(http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/top-shamrock-med.gif) no-repeat; height: 79px; }
                td.shammid img { display: none; }
                td.shammid { background: #00A160 url(http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/mid-shamrock-med.gif) no-repeat; height: 151px; }
                td.maintext p {font-size: 26px; }

            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
                table.one { width: 300px !important; }
                table.two { width: 300px !important; }
                table.three { width: 300px !important; }
                table.four { width: 300px !important; }
                table.five { width: 300px !important; }
                td.shamtop img { display: none; }
                td.shamtop { background: #00A160 url(http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/top-shamrock-sm.gif) no-repeat; height: 79px; }
                td.shammid img { display: none; }
                td.shammid { background: #00A160 url(http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/mid-shamrock-sm.gif) no-repeat; height: 89px; }
            }
</style>        

</head>


<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="one" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#00a160" class="shamtop" style="background: #00A160; margin: 0px;"><img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/top-shamrock-lrg.gif" width="600" height="79"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="two">
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="maintext" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 32px; line-height:120%; color: #000; background: #FFF; padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"><p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 16px;">In honor of St. Patrick’s Day we’d like to save you some <span style="color: #00a160;">GREEN</span>!</p></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="three">
          <tr>
            <td class="shammid" bgcolor="#b7da63" style="background: #b7da63;"><img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/mid-shamrock-lrg.gif" width="600" height="195"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#b7da63" style="background: #b7da63; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; line-height:120%; color: #000; padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"><p style="font-size:22px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 7px;">Enter to Win $200 Towards a NEW Print Item.</p>
          <p style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">All entries must be made by the end of day today.  <br>
          Five winners will be drawn.</p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  align="center" bgcolor="#b7da63" style="background: #b7da63; padding: 0px 20px 15px 20px; text-align:center;"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/enter-to-win-btn.gif" width="180" height="45"></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="four">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" class="contact" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:115%; color: #333; background: #FFF; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
            <table width="275" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="logo">
              <tr>
                <td class="poslogo"><a href="http://www.poscorp.com/home.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/pos_logo_hc.gif" alt="POS Professional Office Services, Inc." width="272" height="45"></a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
             <table width="275" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="info">
              <tr>
                <td><p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 100%; color: #333; font-weight:bold; margin:20px 0px 5px 0px; text-align:right;">800.331.4976&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.poscorp.com/home.html" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold; color: #333; text-decoration: none;">www.poscorp.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/professional-office-services" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/linkedin.jpg" alt="LinkedIn" width="16" height="16" border="0" style="vertical-align:bottom;"/></a></p></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="five">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height:115%; color: #FFF; background: #00a160; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; margin:0px; font-style:italic;"><p>This offer is non-transferable and entries are limited to one entry per recipient.<br>
          Contest winners will be notified by March 19th.</p></td>
          </tr>
        </table> 

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html
```

Comment: You've got the `height` and `width` specified in the img tag but aren't changing them so the images are still trying to render at the larger size.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not sure if I'm following you. I've setup the width/height like this on other emails with no problem. I removed the width and height from the image within the body tags. It still doesn't work. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I'd missed those getting updated in the css somehow.  I believe the caffeine helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your html has a defined style which is overriding the css on your elements. For instance, changing:

```
<td class="shammid" bgcolor="#b7da63" style="background: #b7da63;">
  <img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/mid-shamrock-lrg.gif" width="600" height="195">
</td>
```

to

```
<td class="shammid" bgcolor="#b7da63">
  <img src="http://www.poscorp.com/emarketing/2015/images/mid-shamrock-lrg.gif" width="600" height="195">
</td>
```

Yields the result you're looking for.

You should also consider removing the `bgcolor` attribute as it has been deprecated in HTML5.